# document.getElementById works, but $ is throwing an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here :

```
<select id="test">
        <option value="1">test1</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
        <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

In my script I have these two line of code, one is JavaScript and another one is jquery  like so :

```
var e = document.getElementById("user");
var e1 = $("#user");
```

I even printed out those in my console like this :

```
 console.log(e)
 console.log(e1)
```

They are printing same thing. But when I write a `on` change event code like this :

```
$("#user").change(function() {
        console.log(e.options[e.selectedIndex].text)
 });
```

It is exactly printing what I choose from drop down. That this javascript way of fetching from dom is working. The same thing with `e1` like so :

```
$("#user").change(function() {
    console.log(e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text)
 });
```

is throwing an error :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
(anonymous function)create:167
f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
f.event.add.i.h.handle.i`

(seen from chrome's developer tools)

Whats going on? I'm new to both Javascript and jquery! Why in my case jquery is not working?

Comment: Actually, they don't print the same thing. The other prints a DOM object and the other prints a jQuery object.

Comment: @Juhana : Oh! `console.log` just fooled me! *_*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using jquery and `e1` is a jquery object try:

```
console.log(e1.find('option:selected').text())
```

To grab the actual element you can use `get()`:

```
var select = $('#select').get(0) // Grab original DOM element
select.options // It'll work now...
```

Comment: Because it's not just a regular element, it's a jQuery collection. See edit

Answer (score 4):

```
var e = document.getElementById("user");
```

this creates an javascript object.

```
var e1 = $("#user");
```

This creates an jquery object. You can't use javascript properties on this. You must use jquery properties.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(e1[0].options[e1[0].selectedIndex].text)`

Answer (score 0):

The select menu you give at the top of your article has an id of 'test' not 'user'. I assume the code you're actually working with has an id of 'user'. e1 is a jQuery object, so to access it's value use e1.val() instead of e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text. You're mixing javascript code with jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

e1 is a jQuery object because you used jQuery to select it.  It is not the normal js dom element, which is how you are trying to use it.

This should work better:

$("#user").change(function() {
    console.log(e1.val());
 });

val() is a jQuery function that provides a unified wrapper around form element values so you don't need to find the selected index, access that from the select obj, etc.  This is one of the things jQuery does that makes life easier.